# Two checkbuttons to toggle sound not working right

Tags: python-2.7, button, tkinter

```
    self.mb = Menubutton ( self.window2, text="Sound Toggler", relief=RAISED )
    self.mb.grid(row=4, column = 0)
    self.mb.menu  =  Menu ( self.mb, tearoff = 0 )
    self.mb["menu"]  =  self.mb.menu

    self.ONSound  = IntVar()
    self.ONSound.set(1)
    self.OFFSound = IntVar()
    self.OFFSound.set(0)

    self.mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="ONSound", variable=self.ONSound, command = self.turnON(), onvalue=1,offvalue=0)
    self.mb.menu.add_checkbutton ( label="OFFSound", variable=self.OFFSound, command = self.turnOFF(), onvalue=1,offvalue=0)

def turnON(self):
    self.ONSound.set(1)
    self.OFFSound.set(0)

def turnOFF(self):
    self.ONSound.set(0)
    self.OFFSound.set(1)
```

My goal is to turn these two check buttons to toggle sound On and OFF and in doing so only one of these check buttons can be on/off at a single time.  Currently this effect is not working and I've been looking at my code for an hour and can't find the problem.  Everything shows up when my full program is run but this ON/OFF toggle doesn't work how I want it to.

All help is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Why not have a single checkbutton that turns sound on when checked and off when unchecked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you set the `command` to a function call instead of a funciton reference. This makes the functions run once and assign the return value (`None`) to `command`. You should remove the parentheses after the function names.

---

To make two options of which only one can be selected however, why don't you make them [radiobuttons](https://web.archive.org/web/20201112020724/http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/menu.htm#Tkinter.Menu.add_radiobutton-method)? Then it's as simple as

```
self.Sound  = IntVar()

self.mb.menu.add_radiobutton(label= "ONSound", variable=self.Sound, value=1)
self.mb.menu.add_radiobutton(label="OFFSound", variable=self.Sound, value=0)
```

Comment: I didn't think to use radiobuttons.  In doing this how do I get which radiobutton is activated?  I need to grab the active button and change my value of my self.soundToggle variable to 0 or 1 representing Off and ON sounds.

Comment: In this way, `self.Sound` is an `IntVar` whose value is 1 when `ONSound` is selected and 0 when `OFFSound` is selected. You can get that value using `self.Sound.get()`.

Comment: everything works flawlessly except that it initially sets OFF sound as checked?  however, I would like to have the default as ON sound

Comment: I found the issue.  I just needed to set Sound as 1 after I created the radiobuttons.  Thanks a ton for the help!